# Debian package (.deb): how determine depends?

Tags: linux, packaging

I have a binary application and I would like to create a Debian package (*.deb) from it. In DEBIAN/control file, I need to add dependencies.
In order to find dependencies, I execute following commands:

```
  > objdump -p greenCity | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libsfml-graphics.so.2.3
  NEEDED               libsfml-system.so.2.3
  NEEDED               libsfml-window.so.2.3
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

Here the control file content:

```
Package: greencity
Version: 1.0
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libsfml-graphics, libsfml-system, libsfml-window
Maintainer: x x <x@x.com>
Section: base
Priority: optional
Homepage: 
Description: xxx
```

Finally, I create the package and I install it. During installation, I get the following error:

> greencity depends on libsfml-graphics; however:   Package
>   libsfml-graphics is not installed.  greencity depends on
>   libsfml-system; however:   Package libsfml-system is not installed. 
>   greencity depends on libsfml-window; however:   Package libsfml-window
>   is not installed.

Info: the packages libsfml-graphics/system/window2.3 are well installed on my Linux.
So, what is the rule to determine the name of the depends ? I tried a lot of possibilities but none of them works :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the Debian packages for this library have the library's major version number appended; *e.g.* `libsfml-graphics2`, `libsfml-system2`, *etc*.

While this is a common pattern for the naming of Debian packages, there are often exceptions. You should always look up the exact name of packages (either in your system's package list, or on https://packages.debian.org/) when writing control files; don't assume that the package name will always match the file name.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I tried libsfml-graphics2 and it didn't work. In fact, the only depends name which seems work is: libsfml-graphics2.3v5. But this kind of dependencies is too restrictive to create a package, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [syntax of Debian control file](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html), you need to provide **package names** in "Depends" section.

You can easily find it with `dpkg-query` command. For example, you need `libgcc_s.so.1` to be present. Then check which package provides it

```
$ dpkg-query  -S 'libgcc_s.so.1'
libgcc1:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
lib32gcc1: /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Now you can write

```
Depends: libgcc1
```